# Error: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: on <ViewController: while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, presentation

Hey everyone and thank you for reading. I am making an app which you can take pictures and retreive pictures from the camera roll and display it on a view. The problem is that when I try to use the button which brings up the camera roll, I get the error "presentation is in progress" as above in the title.

if I comment out the code  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL]; in the viewdidappear method I can bring up the camera roll... I have no idea how to properly dismiss this, I have tried  [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; but to no avail.

here is my code! Thanks for checking it out.

```
-(IBAction)chooseExisting:(id)sender {

[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
imagePicker2 = [[UIImagePickerController  alloc] init];
imagePicker2.delegate = self;
[imagePicker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
while (chooseExistingInt <1) {

overlayView.hidden = false;
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController  alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
    chooseExistingInt ++;
}
}
```

FIXED (maybe) I changed:

```
[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

to

```
[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

Changed the animated to "NO". WTF :s

Comment: is UIImagePickerController UIViewController?

Comment: [This][1] solution may help you.Try to present in main thread


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805643/uipopovercontroller-not-presenting-in-ipad-ios-8/25807599#25807599

Comment: possible dublicates of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942282/uiimagepickercontroller-not-presenting-in-ios-8)

Comment: Except this post is almost 2 years older

Answer (score 4):

Place your code which you want to perform in this

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
//your code 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help you . You are using the **presentviewcontroller** instead of the  **presentModalViewController**

And in the dismissing also use the **dismissModalViewController**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I shall try that. I am getting a warning, saying that "this method is deprecated." is this a problem?

Edit: I tried this, and I got the same error :/

Comment: Deprecation doesn't create any issues

Comment: It may help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805643/uipopovercontroller-not-presenting-in-ipad-ios-8/25807599#25807599