# Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7ca5dc00> on <UIViewController: 0x7b9cac00> which is already presenting (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I got this error in using iPad. But iPhone is worked. Please share the solution. My code is given below.

```
-(void)pickImageFromLibrary
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker10 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker10.delegate = self;
    picker10.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker10.view.tag=100;


        picker10.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker10 animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942282/uiimagepickercontroller-not-presenting-in-ios-8

Answer (score 2):

you should try this code!

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerCopntroller must be presented in popover in iPad. take a look at the following code for iPad:

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver = popover;
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

don't forget to add a strong property for the popover:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
```

here are the delegate methods for dismissing it:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

here is the link to the class reference for more info: [Class Refference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)