# UIPopoverController not presenting in iPad iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I am using `UIPopoverController` in iOS 8 iPad for `imagepicker`.Its working in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8.The popover is not displayed and `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` is called immediately.Please suggest a solution..
Here the code am using:

```
UIPopoverController *popVC= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
_pop = popVC;
_pop.delegate = self;
[_pop presentPopoverFromRect:attachBtnFrame inView:_sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 22):

**Finally found the solution:**
Present the Popover in main thread as below.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0)
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [_pop presentPopoverFromRect:attachBtnFrame inView:_sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
    });
}
```

Comment: if you don't want a delay you could use `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_after`

Comment: This does not work for me.  Is it still working for you in iOS 8.1.1 ??

Comment: @ zezba9000 YES.No change required for 8.1.1

Comment: Thanks for the solution...After spending a lots of hours, I solved in this way.

Answer (score 5):

Put this Method in your appDelegate.m

```
+(BOOL)isIOS8

{
     NSString* version=[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([version integerValue]>=8.0)
     {
         return YES;
     }
     else
     {
         return NO;
     } 
}
```

now, when you want to use PopoverController just Check system OS by above method like

```
if([AppDelegate isIOS8])
```

than use this Method

```
if([AppDelegate isIOS8])
        {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                 ^{[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];});
        }
        else
        {
            [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES ];
        }
```

this Method works for me very well and it should work for you...