# How do I access my photo gallery and video camera using iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, photo-gallery, video-gallery

I am having difficulty accessing my photos and video camera for the iPad only in iOS 8.3. I don't have a problem with the iPhone code. And, this code worked for both devices in iOS 7. Not sure why at this point why this is so. When the popover happens, I select "Choose Existing Photos or Video" and nothing else happens. I do have app permissions set that allows for photo/video gallery access. Here is my code sample. Anyone having a similar problem?

```
    - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex != 2) {
            imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
            imagePickerController.delegate = self;

            if (buttonIndex == 0) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

                [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
            } else {

                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];

                    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(54.0f, 120.0f, 660.0f, 380.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

                } else {
                    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check popover or viewController is nil

Comment: I am receiving the following Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7a94fe00>  on <CreatePictureNoteVC: 0x79fac060> which is already presenting (null)

Comment: both do appear to be nil

Comment: iOS 8 does not use UIPopoverController. You need to rewrite and modernize for iOS 8.

Comment: oh ok...wow. will check into it. thanks

Comment: This link worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25807599/1854946

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to check that your viewcontroller is nil or not.